# What Is the Syntax for Including the Service Name in a Connection String?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle, database-administration

I have a C# ASP.Net MVC web application. I am trying to successfully connect to an Oracle database.
I am getting a "ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor" error.
I do not have access to the server the database is on. But I do have access to Oracle SQL Developer, which I have installed on my machine.

In my C# code I am setting the connection string like this:

`ConnectionString = "DataSource=XXX.XX.XXX.XXX/abcd,1521;User ID=userid;Password=password;";`

abcd should be the service name. and 1521 is the port number.

I understand that my connection string might not be the cause of the error, but I want to rule it out. Also, I know the more proper way of doing things is probably to set the connection string in web.config and retrieve it as needed, but I am doing it this way just for ease of testing until I know I am able to connect to the database successfully.

What is weird to me, is that I was able to connect to the database using Oracle SQL Developer using the same IP address, port number, service name, username, and password I am using in my connection string.

Primarily, I would like help knowing if my connection string looks valid. If you have additional thoughts about what the issue could be, that would also be appreciated.

using this command in Oracle SQL Developer:
`select sys_context('userenv','service_name') from dual;`

I am able to determine that the service name I am using in my connection string is one that exists, although I guess this does not guarantee that the service is up.
I am not a DBA by any means. In fact, I am still new to .Net and web development in general, but I have been assigned to troubleshoot this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A tip for you: create a new text file on your desktop and rename it to `a.udl`, double click it to see a familiar data connection dialog, change the provider to oracle, set all the settings, test it, save it, then name it back to `a.txt` and open it in notepad; it's your connection string

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you so much for the tip. I do not, however, have Oracle in the provider list. The application it chose by default to open the .udl file is OLE DB Core Services. What application should I use to open the url? I tried choosing the sqldeveloper.exe from my downloads, but that just launches Oracle SQL Devleloper.

Comment: Urgh.. Maybe a driver issue there - OLE DB COre Services is the right app. Instead try this similar tip: Add a new DataSet to your project, open it, right click anywhere on the surface and add a table adapter. Make a new connection string, fill out the dialog for Oracle, test, save.. The connection string will end up stashed in your app settings when you finish the wizard (just fire a query like `select * from dual` in. I'll be keen to know if this shows your oracle driver when the other tip didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out. My connection string format I don't t think was correct. I changed it to be:

```
ConnectionString = "DataSource=XXX.XX.XXX.XXX/abcd;User ID=userid;Password=password;";
```

Basically, I just took off the port number. In my case, the default port was what I needed anyway. Not sure what I would have done had I needed to specify the port number.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall seeing the following format

```
DataSource=XXX.XX.XXX.XXX/abcd,1521
```

as valid (which doesn't mean its not, I've just not seen it).

The more common ones I've seen are:

```
DataSource=XXX
```

where XXX is a reference to your tnsnames.ora file

```
DataSource=//nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn/service_name
DataSource=//nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn:port/service_name
```

So maybe try those variants and see how you go.  There's also more definitive list of alternatives at https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/connection-strings-for-oracle/

Answer (score 0):

As new to Oracle I struggled a few days finding solution to this
this article helped me alot

As of Oracle 21 c

This is my Connection string for C#

```
Password=dev;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Dev;Data Source=localhost:1521/XEPDB1
```

Keep in mind Dev is Username which is also the Schema name for Oracle